# How do I prevent the same set of error messages from showing after form submission in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, validation

I am trying to display error messages when the form is submitted empty. However, the same error messages showed up based on the number of times I clicked the button. How do I show unique set of error messages instead of looping?

Here's how it looks:

[image]

Here's the code I have tried to check if form is empty:

```
 checkForm(){
   
    if (this.staffName && this.designation && this.staffId && this.skills) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!this.staffName) {
      this.errors.push('Staff Name required.');
    }
    if (!this.designation) {
      this.errors.push('Designation required.');
    }
    // if (this.password = '') {
    //   alert('Password required.');
    // }
    if(!this.staffId){
      this.errors.push('Staff ID required.')
    }
    if(this.skills === []){
      this.errors.push('Select at least one.');
    }
    if(this.errors.length){ 
      return this.errors
    }
    else{
      for (var staff of this.info){
        if(staff.staff_id == this.staffId){
          this.errors.push('This Staff exist! Please try again.');
          return this.errors
        }
        else{
          this.addStaff()
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Here's the code I used to display the errors if the form is empty:

```
  <p v-if="errors.length">
      <b>Please correct the following error(s):</b>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(error, idx) in errors" :key="idx">{{ error }}</li>
      </ul>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Easiest method I can think of:

Clear the array every time you fire the button

you can either do it on the `template` tag

```html
<button 
  type="submit" 
  @click="errors = []"
>
```

or in the `checkForm` method

```js
checkForm() {
  this.errors = [] //make sure to place it at the top
}
```

### Mentionables

also, not within your question but you cannot compare array with `===`, or even `==`, it will always return false

I am referring to this

```js
    if(this.skills === []){
      this.errors.push('Select at least one.');
    }
```

since you just want to know whether it is empty, use `.length` instead. But if you want to compare like

```js
[1, 2] == [1, 2]
```

it will always return false, but you can google up the solution easily as it is very popular issue that JS developers face

Comment: thanks method 2 works for me i forgot to empty the array at the top

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pussing error messages to array you can use Object or even if you want to stick with error you can use array `include` function to check if that already in array or not. Like:

```
if (!this.errors.includes('Staff Name required.');
{
    this.errors.push('Staff Name required.');
}
```

Or if you want to use Object you can do something like

```
data() {
   return {
      errors: {
           staf_name: null,
       }

   }
}
```

then in your code you can update it like `this.errors.staf_name = '';`

Thanks

Comment: then how to display the errors if I am using the Object way?

Comment: Either you can loop or add statement one by one, but the + advanage you can show error below the input field.

Look these code : https://github.com/lablnet/lablnet.com/blob/main/src/views/ContactView.vue#L137